# Magento Invalid Block Type in C:\wamp\www\mg1\app\Mage.php:595

Tags: php, magento

I've just installed an simple extension to display attributes grouped by attribute set. After installing it I'm getting this error:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in C:\wamp\www\mg1\app\Mage.php:595
```

Below are the 2 files (i manually found them) that it installed:
Can anyone tell me where I can start looking first to fix the cause of error?

**A layout file:**
\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\AttributesAsGroup.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <catalog_product_view>

        <reference name="content">
        <block name="product.info" >

        <block type="Webguys_AttributesAsGroup/Groupview" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="webguys/attributesasgroup/groupview.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        </block>

        </block>
    </reference>

    </catalog_product_view>

</layout>
```

**Here is the template file** 
\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\webguys\attributesasgroup

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>

<?php if($_additionalgroup = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="box-collateral box-additional">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_additionalgroup as $_additional): $i++; ?>
        <h3><?php echo $this->__( $_additional['title'] )?></h3>
        <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>">
            <col width="25%" />
            <col />
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>')</script>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: put AttributesAsGroup module file config.xml file

Comment: Sorry Amit I don't understand what u mean. Can you please describe a little more?

Answer (score 0):

this extension is not suiable extension.

```
i  have modify app\code\community\Webguys\AttributesAsGroup\etc\config.xml in
```

and code is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Webguys_AttributesAsGroup>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Webguys_AttributesAsGroup>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <attributesasgroup>
                <class>Webguys_AttributesAsGroup_Block</class>
            </attributesasgroup>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <attributesasgroup>
                    <file>attributesasgroup.xml</file>
                </attributesasgroup>

            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
and file name AttributesAsGroup.xml change to attributesasgroup.xml
```

and code of this code:

this file code is

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>

        <reference name="content">
            <block name="product.info" >

                <block type="attributesasgroup/groupview" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="webguys/attributesasgroup/groupview.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>

            </block>
        </reference>

    </catalog_product_view>

</layout>
```

Comment: Amit, it seems to work a little more now but the "Additional Information" tab now is missing in my Product View PAge.

I'm getting an Invalid Block error.

Inside my catalog.xml it looks like this:

<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">

Do u think something needs to be corrected in the attributesasgroup.xml file?